# How to parse xml file with System.Xml.Linq

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, xml-parsing

I have Some data stored in xml files which was serialized using this http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/725375/Tiny-XML-Serialization-for-Cplusplus xml serializer. So my Xml Files Looks like:

Type 1:

```
<SerializableClass Type="ApplicationSettings" Version="2.1">
<Member Name="Setting1">Settings string 1</Member>
<Member Name="Setting2">Settings string 2</Member>
<Member Name="Setting3">Settings string 3</Member>
<Member Name="Setting4">1234</Member>
<Member Name="Setting5">5678</Member>
<Member Name="Setting6">false</Member>
<Member Name="Setting7">true</Member>
<Class Name="Login" Type="DatabaseLogin" Version="1">
    <Member Name="HostName">my.db.Settings.server.local</Member>
    <Member Name="Port">2000</Member>
    <Member Name="User">john.smith</Member>
    <Member Name="Password">newPassword</Member>
</Class>
<Collection Name="LastUsedDocuments">
    <Class Type="LastUsedDocument" Version="1">
        <Member Name="Name">Document #1</Member>
        <Member Name="Path">c:\temp\</Member>
        <Member Name="Size"></Member>
    </Class>
    <Class Type="LastUsedDocument" Version="1">
        <Member Name="Name">Document #2</Member>
        <Member Name="Path">c:\temp\</Member>
        <Member Name="Size"></Member>
    </Class>
    <Class Type="LastUsedDocument" Version="1">
        <Member Name="Name">Document #3</Member>
        <Member Name="Path">c:\temp\</Member>
        <Member Name="Size"></Member>
    </Class>
    <Class Type="LastUsedDocument" Version="1">
        <Member Name="Name">Document #4</Member>
        <Member Name="Path">c:\temp\</Member>
        <Member Name="Size"></Member>
    </Class>
    <Class Type="LastUsedDocument" Version="1">
        <Member Name="Name">Document #5</Member>
        <Member Name="Path">c:\temp\</Member>
        <Member Name="Size"></Member>
    </Class>
</Collection>
```

now I want to parse such xml files using System.xml.linq tools and I found it not so easy because I need to check every "Name" attribute to find out what is the type of object.

its much easier for me to read such type of xml:
Type 2:

```
    <LastUsedDocuments>
    <LastUsedDocument>
        <Name>Document #1</Name>
        <Path>c:\temp\</Path>
        <Size></Size>
    </LastUsedDocument>
    <LastUsedDocument>
        <Name>Document #1</Name>
        <Path>c:\temp\</Path>
        <Size></Size>
    </LastUsedDocument>     
</LastUsedDocuments>
```

but I can't rewrite all that xml files, so I am looking for a way to ro read this type 1 xml file as easily as this type 2 xml

can you help me how to do that with system.xml.linq?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My preferred method is this:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(xmlByteBuffer))
{
  XElement root = XElement.Load(ms);

  IEnumerable<XElement> res =
      from el in root.Elements("Member")
      where (string)el.Attribute("Name") == "Setting1"
      select el;
}
```

Edit: Your XML appears to be incorrect. Your starting tag is "SerializableClass" and ending tag is "Collection". You may have to adjust the search so you're querying through the 'Collection' XElement. `XElement child1 = root.Element("Collection");`

Comment: sorry I didn't copied it correctly (fully). thanks much it worked